# Как интегрировать boost в Qt чтобы не задавать абсолютные пути в каждом проекте

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Платформа Windows.
Понятно, что все можно прописать в проект. Но когда разработка ведется многими людьми на разных машинах, каждому придется абсолютные подстраивать пути в проекте под себя. А если файл проекта хранится в системе контроля версий, то вообще кошмар.
Как решить эту проблему?
Пока складываю Boost в папки include и lib компилятора, но хочется чего-то более человеческого.

Comment: Это зависит от системы сборки, которую используете. Я так полагаю, Вы используете qmake, так?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет прописывание пути к `boost` в переменные среды системы. К сожалению не имею под рукой установленную `windows` чтобы проверить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случаи, если вы используете систему сборки *сmake*, то достаточно в файле *CMakeList.txt* прописать поиск пакета Boost в системе с помощью команды [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html)

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS *boost libraries here*) 

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) // подключаем заголовочный файлы бибилотеки в проект
    add_executable(progname file1.cxx file2.cxx) 
    target_link_libraries(progname ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) // прилинковываем библиотеки boost.
endif()
```

Например, если вы используете компоненты filesystem и regex, то вы должны написать так

```
find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS filesystem regex)
```

Таким образом, cmake автоматически найдет путь, где лежать заголовники и либы библиотеки boost и подключить их в ваш проект.
 
   Более подробно ознакомиться, как работает команда find_package в cmake,  [здесь](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake%3AHow_To_Find_Libraries#How_package_finding_works)

Answer (score 1):

Я пользуюсь VisualStudio, для сборки нескольких проектов с boost у меня используется переменная в студии `$(BoostHome)`, которая эквивалентна  переменной среды с таким же именем, пути для `include` и `lib` задаются относительно неё. Таким образом каждый разработчик может установить буст куда угодно, задав путь в свойствах своей системы. Также все проекты будут использовать одну и ту же копию буста, если требуется.

Не знаю точно, как задать в случае CMake и прочих систем сборки, но думаю, что они тоже поддерживают данный приём.